# How can i use methods of a class to a new class?

Tags: java

Well I have a menu method in class A which shows the menu in the emulator when clicked.

How can use that method to my new class B

I want this methods to be use by class B too :

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    //inflates the menu or this will show the activity
    MenuInflater awesome = getMenuInflater();
    awesome.inflate(R.menu.main, menu); //main is the xml main

    return true;
}

//this will manipulate the menu
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menuSweet:
        startActivity(new Intent("Sweet"));
        return true;

    case R.id.menuToast:
        Toast andEggs = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        "This is a toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        andEggs.show();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: make the method static and access it with ClassA.(method)

Comment: Read "Head first Core Java" ASAP.

Comment: Get a reference to a `A` object and call the methods on it?  I must be misunderstanding the question...

Comment: Create the oject of class A in class B. With the help of class A Object you can access its method

Comment: thanks for the answers, i fixed it , sorry guys i got confused a bit in android, but i'm quite familiar in java as well as the basics. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to do, you usually have two big options (among many): Subclassing and Composition:

### Subclassing

So if your class B is a specialization of class A's behavior (B **is a** special case of A), extend class A:

```
class A {
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item);
}

class B extends A {
   // some methods only B has.
}
```

Thus you may call

```
B b = new B();
b.onOptionsItemSelected(someItem);
```

### Composition

The second option is wrapping the method call to A by it's own method of the same name (so B **has an** A object and uses it):

```
class B {
    private A a = new A();

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(Item someItem) {
       a.onOptionsItemSelected(someItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your first answer my qustion is what if i extend other class in b? like the activity class. More likely the 2nd answer fits to be the solution.. thanks man! cheers!

Comment: Of course, if you already have "B extends Activity" (or something like that) than Inheritance is no longer an option.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting this, if I didn't misunderstand?

```
class A
{
    public boolean menu(){
        System.out.println("Inside Menu");
        return true;
    }
}
class B
{
    public void testMethod()
    {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.menu());
    }
}
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b =new B();
        b.testMethod();
    }
}
```